# Relationship with reputation and downvote

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

If I accept any answer which got down votes,
does my reputation goes down also? Or is there no change?

Or still the same way by getting 2 points for accepting it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You get 2 points from accepting an answer (unless it's your own answer of course) regardless of the score the answer has.

Though it does seem odd to be accepting a negatively scored answer.

Comment: then i can accept this answer  sure :D..no tension

Comment: Sometimes people prefer the easy and "less correct" way so they accept answer that directly answer their need but does not show good practice hence downvoted. Saw it happen many times. When others are looking in the answers, they should consider using the highest voted answers instead so it's all good I guess. @Tahmina any specific reason for asking this, or just curious?

Comment: one of my question's ans got negative vote .Who give this vote i do not know.But the question was right.So before accept the ans i ask here..  :)